# Ajax function stops automatically working after a "Failed to load resources" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to update some info in my page. I used the `$.when` `$.then` functions to identify when the call is over and should activate the timer.

The issue here is that when the call gets a "Failed to load resources" error (no matter which one of them), it will simply stop working at the middle of the execution, and without resetting the timer.

This is the code:

```
function UpdateCODGW()
{
    if(CODGW_Running == false && session_ended == false)
    {
        CODGW_Running = true;
        $.when($.ajax({
            url: 'THE_URL',
            data: {ajax: 'gwonline'},
            type: 'post',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(sInfo) {
                if(sInfo.session !== false)
                {
                    session_id = sInfo.session;
                    var gwstatus = $(CODGWID);
                    sInfo.isonline ? CODGW_Offline = 0 : ++CODGW_Offline;
                    if(!sInfo.error && sInfo.isonlinestr !== CODGW_Old && (sInfo.isonline || CODGW_Offline >= 3))
                    {
                        gwstatus.html(sInfo.isonlinestr);
                        CODGW_Old = sInfo.isonlinestr;
                    }
                }
                else
                    session_ended = true;
            },
            failure: function() {

            }
        })).then(function() { if(session_ended == false) { CODGW_Running = false; UpdateCODGWTimer(); } });
    }
}
```

I don't know what I did wrong that the code won't handle such errors.

Comment: I guess when something fails, the `failure` function gets called. Maybe you could add there the Updatetimer code? Just guessing.

Comment: It should be called either way after `$.when` finishes, no matter for the `failure` function.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it by using the `complete` function in the `$.ajax` call instead of `$.when` `$.then`.